# How I can find out 1st and last observation with in group in R for every by group

Tags: r

Hi my data set is as follows

```
dialled     Ringing     state   duration
NA  NA  NA  0
NA  NA  NA  0
NA  NA  NA  0
NA  NA  NA  0
123 NA  NA  0
123 NA  NA  0
123 NA  NA  0
123 NA  NA  60
NA  NA  active  0
NA  NA  active  0
NA  NA  inactive    0
NA  NA  inactive    0
NA  145 inactive    0
NA  145 inactive    0
NA  145 inactive    56
NA  NA  active  0
NA  NA  active  0
NA  NA  inactive    0
222 NA  inactive    0
222 NA  inactive    0
222 NA  inactive    37
NA  NA  active  0
NA  NA  active  0
NA  NA  inactive    0
123 NA  inactive    0
123 NA  inactive    0
123 NA  active  60
NA  NA  active  0
```

I want to get 1st and last obs. for every `dialled` number (repeated one as well, because every call is different). Answer I am looking for is

```
dialled     Ringing     state   duration
123 NA  NA  0
123 NA  NA  60
222 NA  inactive    0
222 NA  inactive    37
123 NA  NA  0
123 NA  NA  60
```

I was using the following

```
library(plyr)
ddply(DF, .(Dialled_nbr), function(x) x[c(1,nrow(x)), ]) which gave me

dialled     Ringing     state   duration
123 NA  NA  0
123 NA  NA  60
222 NA  inactive    0
222 NA  inactive    37
```

But answer is not correct. Please help

**New data is**

```
dialled     Ringing     state   duration
123 NA  NA  0
123 NA  NA  0
123 NA  NA  60
123 NA  NA  0
123 NA  NA  0
123 NA  NA  70
222 NA  inactive    0
222 NA  inactive    0
222 NA  inactive    37
123 NA  inactive    0
123 NA  inactive    0
123 NA  active  60


Answer to be
dialled     Ringing     state   duration
123 NA  NA  0
123 NA  NA  60
123 NA  NA  0
123 NA  NA  70
222 NA  inactive    0
222 NA  inactive    37
123 NA  inactive    0
123 NA  active  60
```

Comment: Wait, what??  You just completely changed everything an hour after you posted the question and got two pretty good answers

Comment: @akrun yes it should be

Comment: @akrun I am not able to use data.table_1.9.5

Comment: @akrun which version of r and R studio neede for this?

Comment: @akrun Thanks.....How I can extract 1st row for every group....i.e<Pre>dialled Ringing    state duration
#5      123      NA     <NA>        0

Comment: If you had looked into the updated solution, `df1[!duplicated(grp),]` would give the 1st row for every group

Comment: @akrun on how I can get first and last obs for two consicutive dialled numbers which are same....

Comment: @Lucy I did check the update, but it is not clear about the condition.  For example, the first 4 rows of your expected output, which has the same `dialled` `123`

Comment: @akrun, yes that is the output I am looking for...bcoz every call is different than other

Comment: @Lucy I updated the post. Please check

Comment: @akrun can you help me on one problem

Comment: @Lucy Yes Can you post it as a new question? Thanks.

Comment: @akrun    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213620/how-i-can-find-out-1st-and-last-observation-with-in-group-in-r-for-every-by-grou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option with [`data.table_1.9.5`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/).  Create the "data.table" from "data.frame" using `setDT`, remove the `NA` values in "dialled" column (`!is.na(dialled)`), generate grouping variable by using `rleid` on "Dialled_nbr", get the row index of the first and last rows for the levels of grouping variable (`.I(c(1L, .N)]`), finally subset the "dt1" based on the row index.

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- setDT(df)[!is.na(dialled)]
dt1[dt1[,.I[c(1L, .N)],rleid(dialled)]$V1]
#    dialled Ringing    state duration
#1:     123      NA       NA        0
#2:     123      NA       NA       60
#3:     222      NA inactive        0
#4:     222      NA inactive       37
#5:     123      NA inactive        0
#6:     123      NA   active       60
```

Or using `base R`

```
df1 <- df[!is.na(df$dialled),]
grp<-  inverse.rle(within.list(rle(df1$dialled), 
                    values <- seq_along(values)))

df1[!duplicated(grp)|!duplicated(grp,fromLast=TRUE),]
#    dialled Ringing    state duration
#5      123      NA     <NA>        0
#8      123      NA     <NA>       60
#19     222      NA inactive        0
#21     222      NA inactive       37
#25     123      NA inactive        0
#27     123      NA   active       60
```

#### Update

Based on the new dataset,

```
grp <- cumsum(c(TRUE,df$duration[-nrow(df)]!=0))
df[!duplicated(grp)|!duplicated(grp,fromLast=TRUE),]
#   dialled Ringing    state duration
#1      123      NA     <NA>        0
#3      123      NA     <NA>       60
#4      123      NA     <NA>        0
#6      123      NA     <NA>       70
#7      222      NA inactive        0
#9      222      NA inactive       37
#10     123      NA inactive        0
#12     123      NA   active       60
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(dialled = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
 123L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 222L, 222L, 222L, 
 NA, NA, NA, 123L, 123L, 123L, NA), Ringing = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 145L, 145L, 145L, NA, NA, NA, 
 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), state = c(NA, NA, NA, 
 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "active", "active", "inactive", "inactive", 
 "inactive", "inactive", "inactive", "active", "active", "inactive", 
 "inactive", "inactive", "inactive", "active", "active", "inactive", 
 "inactive", "inactive", "active", "active"), duration = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 60L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 56L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 37L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 60L, 0L)), .Names = 
 c("dialled", "Ringing", "state", "duration"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -28L))
```

#### newdata

```
 df <- structure(list(dialled = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
 222L, 222L, 222L, 123L, 123L, 123L), Ringing = c(NA, NA, NA, 
 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), state = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
 NA, NA, "inactive", "inactive", "inactive", "inactive", "inactive", 
 "active"), duration = c(0L, 0L, 60L, 0L, 0L, 70L, 0L, 0L, 37L, 
 0L, 0L, 60L)), .Names = c("dialled", "Ringing", "state", "duration"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two options. First we'll need to set up a couple of things that will be used in both options.

```
## remove rows where 'dialled' is NA 
ndf <- DF[!is.na(DF$dialled),]
## run-length encoding on the 'dialled' column in 'ndf'
le <- rle(ndf$dialled)$lengths
```

**Option 1:** Create an integer vector of row numbers to use for a subset.

```
ndf[cumsum(mapply(c, 1L, le-1L)), ]
#    dialled Ringing    state duration
# 5      123      NA     <NA>        0
# 8      123      NA     <NA>       60
# 19     222      NA inactive        0
# 21     222      NA inactive       37
# 25     123      NA inactive        0
# 27     123      NA   active       60
```

If you prefer not to loop, then you can replace the `mapply` call with `vec`, defined as

```
vec <- replace(integer(2*length(le))+1L, c(FALSE, TRUE), le-1L)
```

**Option 2:** Add a helper `id` column. Then use `dplyr` functions to get the first and last rows based on that new id column.

```
library(dplyr)    
## updated data with new column
DF2 <- cbind(id = rep.int(seq_along(le), le), ndf)    
## group by id and filter on the first and last rows
slice(group_by(DF2, id), c(1, n()))
#   id dialled Ringing    state duration
# 1  1     123      NA       NA        0
# 2  1     123      NA       NA       60
# 3  2     222      NA inactive        0
# 4  2     222      NA inactive       37
# 5  3     123      NA inactive        0
# 6  3     123      NA   active       60
```

You can remove the helper column if you want, but it might come in handy later too.

Comment: Here is another option using `dplyr`  `ndf %>% group_by(id=cumsum(Dialled_nbr!=lag(Dialled_nbr, default=TRUE))) %>% slice(c(1L, n()))`