# How I can find out 1st and last observation with in group in R for every by group, when 2 groups are repeated one after another

Tags: r

data is below

```
dialled     Ringing     state   duration
NA  NA  NA  0
NA  NA  NA  0
NA  NA  NA  0
NA  NA  NA  0
123 NA  NA  0
123 NA  NA  0
123 NA  NA  0
123 NA  NA  60
NA  NA  active  0
NA  NA  active  0
NA  NA  inactive    0
NA  NA  inactive    0
123 NA  inactive    0
123 NA  inactive    0
123 NA  inactive    0
NA  NA  inactive  0
NA  NA  inactive  0
NA  NA  inactive    0
222 NA  inactive    0
222 NA  inactive    0
222 NA  inactive    37
NA  NA  active  0
NA  NA  active  0
NA  NA  inactive    0
123 NA  inactive    0
123 NA  inactive    0
123 NA  active  60
NA  NA  active  0
NA  NA  active  0
NA  NA  active  0
NA  NA  active  0
123 NA  inactive    0
123 NA  inactive    0
123 NA  inactive    0


answer i am looking for is

dialled     Ringing     state   duration
123 NA  NA          0
123 NA  NA          60
123 NA  inactive    0
123 NA  inactive    0
222 NA  inactive    0
222 NA  inactive    37
123 NA  inactive    0
123 NA  inactive    60
123 NA  inactive    0
123 NA  inactive    0
```

also If you can help me to get the immediate next row, after last row of every by group and Rbind them

Answer (score 1):

In `data.table v1.9.5`, there's a new function `rleid()` that helps accomplish this task fairly straightforward. You can install it by following [these instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation):

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if (!is.na(dialled[1L])) .SD[c(1L, .N)], 
                by=.(dialled, rleid(dialled))]
#     dialled rleid Ringing    state duration
#  1:     123     2      NA       NA        0
#  2:     123     2      NA       NA       60
#  3:     123     4      NA inactive        0
#  4:     123     4      NA inactive        0
#  5:     222     6      NA inactive        0
#  6:     222     6      NA inactive       37
#  7:     123     8      NA inactive        0
#  8:     123     8      NA   active       60
#  9:     123    10      NA inactive        0
# 10:     123    10      NA inactive        0
```

`.SD` contains the subset of data for groups specified in `by =`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a grouping variable "grp" (similar as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006813/how-i-can-find-out-1st-and-last-observation-with-in-group-in-r-for-every-by-grou)). Subset the rows of "df" that are not '0' for "grp", use `slice` to get the first and last row for each "grp", `ungroup` and remove the `grp` variable.

```
rl <- rle(!is.na(df$dialled))
grp <- inverse.rle(within.list(rl, 
      values[values] <- cumsum(values)[values]))
df$grp <- grp
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(grp!=0) %>% 
    group_by(grp) %>% 
    slice(c(1, n()))%>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-grp)
#       dialled Ringing    state duration
#1      123      NA       NA        0
#2      123      NA       NA       60
#3      123      NA inactive        0
#4      123      NA inactive        0
#5      222      NA inactive        0
#6      222      NA inactive       37
#7      123      NA inactive        0
#8      123      NA   active       60
#9      123      NA inactive        0
#10     123      NA inactive        0
```

Or a `base R` option would be to get the row index of first and last rows of subset dataset "df1" based on "grp" and then use it to extract the rows.

```
df1 <- df[grp!=0,]
df2 <- df1[unlist(tapply(1:nrow(df1), grp[grp!=0],
           FUN=function(x) c(head(x,1), tail(x,1)))),]
```

#### Update

It is not clear from the comments.  Perhaps this helps

```
 df2 %>%
    group_by(grp) %>% 
    filter(any(duration>0)) %>% 
    slice(1)
 #    dialled Ringing    state duration grp
 #1     123      NA       NA        0   1
 #2     222      NA inactive        0   3
 #3     123      NA inactive        0   4
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(dialled = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 123L, 123L, 123L, 
123L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 123L, 123L, 123L, NA, NA, NA, 222L, 222L, 
222L, NA, NA, NA, 123L, 123L, 123L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 123L, 123L, 
123L), Ringing = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), state = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
 NA, NA, "active", "active", "inactive", "inactive", "inactive", 
 "inactive", "inactive", "inactive", "inactive", "inactive", "inactive", 
 "inactive", "inactive", "active", "active", "inactive", "inactive", 
 "inactive", "active", "active", "active", "active", "active", 
 "inactive", "inactive", "inactive"), duration = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 60L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L, 37L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 60L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L)), .Names = c("dialled", "Ringing", "state", "duration"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -34L))
```

Comment: @arun I am not able to install data.table_1.9.5

Comment: @akrun.....after this how I can get 1st row of every dialled number from the produced output....how can I get this.....your solution is working fine.......

Comment: @Lucy I updated the solution.  Can you please check?